# Getting a Gradle build to work with TFS2017

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to kick off a Gradle build using on-site TFS 2017 for the first time and I get a window saying All Possible Agents Are Disabled. What do I need to do to enable an agent to work for a Gradle build? I've installed Java SE Development Kit 10. What else do I have to do? I've googled "tfs 2017 Waiting for an enabled agent. All possible agents are disabled" and "enable a TFS 2017 agent for gradle builds" and all I see are the generic gradle builds pages on learn.microsoft.com.

[image]

[image]

EDIT: 4-26-18 9:42 AM:

OK - I realized that for some reason it was looking at Agent (TFS2017_Agent) which was not enabled, but I don't understand why it wouldn't go with one of the enabled pools. So I enabled the pool and it kicked off. (It failed because apparently I need to create a new endpoint (it says nothing about this in the documentation that I saw), but at least the build kicked off. Still no idea why it has an affinity for that particular agent.

Comment: I suspect that the capability of other build agents does not meet your build requirement.

Answer (score 0):

For now, in TFS 2017 it picks the agent in the order that they are registered **if the agents are all idle when a build is queued**, rather than randomly selecting an agent.

According to your description, that should be the root cause why TFS build server always pick up that particular agent.

There has been a user voice  [**here**](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/17701630-build-agent-priority) to suggest the feature to set *Build Agent Priority*,       you can go and vote it up, TFS PM will kindly review your suggestion.

Currently as a workaround, you can set the [demands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/options#demands) in build definitions to force building with the specific agents. To do that, you can reference below articles:   [How to send TFS build to a specific agent or server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericparvin/2017/02/08/how-to-send-tfs-build-to-a-specific-agent-or-server/)

Comment: But the agent it is choosing is disabled and all others are enabled.That's the problem. As it turns out I can't connect to Github Enterprise using TFS so I won't be needing this anyway :-(

Comment: @Ben_G To  choose Git repo in GitHub **Enterprise** as a Repository type which is only support by VSTS for now, you could take a look at the table in this thread: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/repository?view=vsts